# Firebase Storage error saving rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am getting this error on Firebase Storage rules:

```
Error saving rules – The request cannot be identified with a client
project. Please pass a valid API key with the request.
```

and the rule is the default one, I am trying to copy paste the default one:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/myapp1.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you might want to double check, you don't need to change the rule or copy/paste it to start...

your app name seems a bit strange, it's usually something along the lines of:

```
authDomain: "myapp1-b4abb.firebaseapp.com"
```

In your app, that is on the HTML or JS file, you need to config Firebase( you get the information on the console from the add firebase to  your web app button:

```
var config = {
 apiKey: "",
 authDomain: "",
 databaseURL: "",
 storageBucket: "",
 messagingSenderId: ""
};
```

I wrote a post on getting started if you need more of a step by step:[Getting started with Firebase Part 1. Setting up.](http://codepen.io/k3no/post/getting-started-with-firebase)

Comment: no everything is alright, the database is working, auth is working, storage is also working, but i get this error when i load the storage rules page.